# JBehave HTML reports - How to display how many stories run

Tags: java, jbehave

In the default HTML Story Reports of JBehave, it displays how many Scenarios run, how many GiventStory Scenarios and how many steps.

What I try to do is to add some informations on it to display how many stories where run.

For example, if I have a scenario with 3 examples it will run 3 stories. Actually it displays only one Scenario in the table and I want a new column for the 3 stories who ran.

Are is my actual configuration:

```
public class JBehaveStoryRunner extends JUnitStories {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public JBehaveStoryRunner() {
        Class<?> thisClass = this.getClass();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("encoding", "UTF-8");
        // @formatter:off
        useConfiguration(new MostUsefulConfiguration()
                .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(thisClass.getClassLoader()))
                .usePendingStepStrategy(new FailingUponPendingStep())
                .useStepdocReporter(new PrintStreamStepdocReporter())
                .useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder()
                        .withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(thisClass))
                        .withDefaultFormats()
                        .withFormats(Format.CONSOLE, Format.TXT, Format.HTML, Format.XML, Format.STATS)
                        .withCrossReference(new CrossReference())
                        .withViewResources(properties)
                        .withFailureTrace(true))
                .useParameterConverters(new ParameterConverters()
                        .addConverters(new ParameterConverters.DateConverter(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"))))
                .useStoryParser(new GherkinStoryParser())
                .useParameterControls(new ParameterControls().useNameDelimiterLeft("[").useNameDelimiterRight("]"))
                .useStepMonitor(new SilentStepMonitor()));
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new SpringStepsFactory(configuration(), applicationContext);
    }

    protected List<String> storyPaths() {
        return new StoryFinder().findPaths(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()), "**/*.story", "**/excluded*.story");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This HTML report is created using [this (jbehave-reports.ftl)](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/master/jbehave-core/src/main/resources/ftl/jbehave-reports.ftl) Freemaker template. If you want to add a new field in this report, you need to customize this template, or create you own copy. 
Personally I would use use XML file (generated when `Format.XML` is used in your configuration), because I don't know Freemaker and have no time to learn it.
The XML file contains all information you need, just parse it and count elements you want to present on your report.
This is an example of data generated for the below example story (in a project based on maven: jbehave-simple-archetype):

```
Scenario: A scenario with some pending steps

Given I am a pending step <Step>
When a good soul will implement me
Then I shall be happy <Val>
Examples:
|Step|Val|
|1|1|
|2|2|
```

---

```
<story path="org/irko/my_jbehave_simple/stories/my.story" title="">
    <scenario keyword="Scenario:" title="A scenario with some pending steps">
        <examples keyword="Examples:">
            <step>Given I am a pending step &lt;Step&gt;</step>
            <step>When a good soul will implement me</step>
            <step>Then I shall be happy &lt;Val&gt;</step>
            <parameters>
                <names>
                    <name>Step</name>
                    <name>Val</name>
                </names>
                <values>
                    <value>1</value>
                    <value>1</value>
                </values>
                <values>
                    <value>2</value>
                    <value>2</value>
                </values>
            </parameters>

            <example keyword="Example:">{Step=1, Val=1}</example>
            <step outcome="successful">
                Given I am a pending step
                <parameter>1</parameter>
            </step>
            <step outcome="successful">When a good soul will implement me</step>
            <step outcome="successful">
                Then I shall be happy
                <parameter>1</parameter>
            </step>

            <example keyword="Example:">{Step=2, Val=2}</example>
            <step outcome="successful">
                Given I am a pending step
                <parameter>2</parameter>
            </step>
            <step outcome="successful">When a good soul will implement me</step>
            <step outcome="successful">
                Then I shall be happy
                <parameter>2</parameter>
            </step>
        </examples>
    </scenario>
</story>
```

Comment: That's one way that I thought but I hoped there were an easier way :-P